# "Software rot" or is there a better term to convey the idea of a slow deterioration of software quality over time?

Tags: word-choice, etymology, terminology, software

I just found this term https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_rot:

> **Software rot**, also known as bit rot, code rot, software erosion,
> software decay, or software entropy is either **a slow deterioration of
> software quality over time** or its diminishing responsiveness that will
> eventually lead to software becoming faulty, unusable, or in need of
> upgrade.

And here https://www.techopedia.com/definition/22202/software-rot (notice their difference)

> **Software rot** refers to the slow degradation in the performance of
> computer software. Such software shows diminished responsiveness,
> lacks updates, may become faulty overtime owing to changes in the
> operating system it is running on and thus may need upgrading.

I would assume **software rot** is not a term most people are aware of. But I can't think of a term to describe the situation of **a slow deterioration of software quality over time** although I guess many people experience that, e.g. IE, Window XP, facebook ? (just to name a few)

Has anyone coined a term for that? Besides, **refactoring** is a term, closed related to  "Software rot" (to counteract that)  most software engineer knows. So why there is no term for "Software rot" ?

BTW, I notice this similar question [Who first used the term "bit rot"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47676/who-first-used-the-term-bit-rot) asked 10 years ago. The meaning there is also slight different that software rot explained in wikipedia.

> Bit rot, also known as bit decay, data rot, or data decay, is a
> colloquial computing term used to describe either a gradual decay of
> storage media or the degradation of a software program over time. The
> latter use of the term implies that software can wear out or rust like
> a physical tool.

Comment: You are asking for a "better" word. What are the criteria? Why are software rot, bit rot, code rot, software erosion, software decay or software entropy not suitable?

Comment: ***Software rot***  appears to be present also in tech dictionaries. https://books.google.it/books?id=P2EtDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA294&dq=%22software+rot%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&source=gb_mobile_search&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjgme-N1-H5AhXGi_0HHSgsBHgQ6AF6BAgEEAM#v=onepage&q=%22software%20rot%22&f=false I don’t see the problem in using the expression.

Comment: One problem I see is there seems no universal definition for it yet,  in my question I already list 3 explanation and I saw more.

Comment: It may take time for new expressions to be commonly recognized. According to Google Books “bit rot” appears to be the more common one. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=software+rot%2C+bit+rot%2C+code+rot%2C+software+erosion+&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csoftware%20rot%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbit%20rot%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccode%20rot%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csoftware%20erosion%3B%2Cc0

Comment: But it is not a new expression if you check the linked question "The oldest reference on Usenet I can find is in the subject line "Creeping Bit Rot in Bnews" in this 24th January 1982 "

Comment: The definitions are not that different. The core idea is that performance and quality degrade. The root cause doesn't have to be a single thing. "Bit rot" seems to be used both for data and software.

Comment: But as a software engineer myself and experienced "software rot" myself many times, performance degrade is just one of problems, definitely not the core problem of it.

Comment: "Why are software rot, bit rot, code rot, software erosion, software decay or software entropy not suitable?" because none of these words are well-known even in the software industry, compared to refactoring I gave in my question.

Comment: Consider the words "bit rot" was first coined in 1982 and still nobody knows it. I just assume there should be a "better" word .

Comment: In my 40 years in the computer biz I've heard "software rot" only a handful of times.  Software doesn't really "wear out", but does become less effective as the operating environment changes.

Comment: I've often heard the term _demo rot_ and _software rot_. I think from context these are clear, at least to a native speaker. This may be cultural habit from the places I've worked as opposed to a widespread phenomena.

Comment: Even though it's not used often, I think the intent will be clear to most people in the industry. I don't think there's a better term, simply because it's not something that we talk about much. Much more common are software bloat and technical debt.

Comment: @Barmar "it's not something that we talk about much" but to me it is something we talk about a lot (in Chinese), we don't have a Chinese term either just explain it as the process of "a slow deterioration of software quality over time". Because IE, window xp are such typical examples , it is easy to understand. But on the other hand, **refactor** and its Chinese translation is a term everyone knows, more well-known to **technical debt**, much more well-known to "software bloat"

Comment: **software bloat** is a term we don't use that much, even its meaning is not that understandable.

Comment: I have heard the term software rot (or code rot) many times. People familiar with code refactoring - https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring - will likely understand it immediately

Answer (score -1):

Obsolescence

Software-obsolescence

Software obsolescence

Comment: This would benefit from your explanation of how these terms answer the question.

Comment: Obsolescence typically refers to something different, i.e. software going out of date, being no longer usable, or no longer supported.